# meta tag og:image for facebook sharing rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I have a page with article, and I can set from back-end an image for the article. In the show action I would like to obtain the meta tag og:image to share the article in facebook also with the image.
I show the image with:

```
<%= image_tag @article.image_url, :class => "img-fluid" %>
```

but I am not able to have the image also in facebook post automatically when I copy and paste the url in facebook.

Do you have any suggestion?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to this article here, you need a bit more setup.

https://www.lewagon.com/blog/setup-meta-tags-rails

1. Create default meta tags in `config/meta.yml` and load them in an initializer:

```
meta_product_name: "Product Name"
meta_title: "Product name - Product tagline"
meta_description: "Relevant description"
meta_image: "cover.png" # should exist in `app/assets/images/`
```

```
# config/initializers/default_meta.rb

# Initialize default meta tags.
DEFAULT_META = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join("config/meta.yml"))
```

You can use them like this in the `application.html.erb`

```
<title><%= meta_title %></title>
<meta name="description" content="<%= meta_description %>">

<!-- Facebook Open Graph data -->
<meta property="og:title" content="<%= meta_title %>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
...
```

I shortened it but see the article for the full code.

2. For dynamic titles or images use Rails' `content_for` method and create a helper method:

```
<!-- app/views/any_model/any_view.html.erb -->
<% content_for :meta_image, image_path(@any_model.photo.path) %>
```

And the helper would look like this:

```
# app/helpers/meta_tags_helper.rb
module MetaTagsHelper
  def meta_image
    meta_image = (content_for?(:meta_image) ? content_for(:meta_image) : DEFAULT_META["meta_image"])
    # little twist to make it work equally with an asset or a url
    meta_image.starts_with?("http") ? meta_image : image_url(meta_image)
  end
end
```

Again, shortened, but you'll find the full code in the source.